# How to add elements from list to label?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a variable like this:

```
List<Double> data = new LinkedList<Double>();
JTextField field = new JTextField(" ");
JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");
JButton button = new JButton(" ");
```

data are values from list, that I need to get from user from JTextField. I need them to be added to a Label: user writes a value in TextField, clicks a button, the value is added to the label, writes a new value, clicks the button again, the value is visible next to the previous, and so on...

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
                //data = Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
                //label.setText(String.valueOf(data));

                for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    data = Double.parseDouble(field.getText()); //not working
                    label.setText(String.valueOf(data));
                }
            }
    });
```

it works only for one double variable (code //)

My questions: how to change double list elements to be addable to the label? How to make new values visible next to the previous values? (loop?)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's the point in reading the same data 10 time ? And writing to the same label 10 times ?

Comment: I need to read new data, new values

Comment: A [mcve] would have saved a lot of guess work and make help more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Statement `label.setText(String.valueOf(data));` do not append the parameter to the label but sets it. In your cycle `data` has always the same value, so its sets 10 times the same string to label's text.

If you want to append the `String.valueOf(data)` to the text of label, you need to build text of label first from your `List`. You could use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) for this:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
data.stream().map(String::valueOf).forEach(joiner::add);
label.setText(joiner.toString());
```

So in `actionPerformed` method, you add `Double.parseDouble(field.getText())` to the list, then build the text as showed before and set it to label using `setText`.

You could find more about how to use StringJoiner [here](http://www.baeldung.com/java-string-joiner).